# Spring Data issue

Tags: spring-data

I have a Spring Boot project and I am using Spring Data for CRUD queries.
I am iterating over an csv file and the first 10 lines are all equals:

```
SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN;.....
SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN;.....
SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN;.....
SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN;.....
...
```

This is a code snippet which I use for debug:

```
Optional<MasterSystem> oms = repository.findBySystem(system);

if(oms.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println("is present:" + system);
} else {
    System.out.println("is NOT present:" + system);
}
```

And this is the result:

```
is NOT present:SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN 
is present:SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN
is present:SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN
is present:SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN
```

As you can see the first result is "NOT present" and the rest are "present" even though I am looking for the same phrase
Any idea?

Thanks
R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an UTF-8 problem.
The csv file I was reading was save with UTF-8 encoding and at the beginning of the first line I got this characters:ï»¿

ï»¿SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN;.....
SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN;.....
SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN;.....
SISTEMA DE ORIENTACIÓN;.....

This was the reason that I was getting a null for the first line

Hope this helps to someone

Regards,
R.